# How can I store inputs given by the user from GUI to a string array in java? I am using java swing to create the GUI

Tags: java

i have created a drop down menu and i want to store which option the user is choosing from the menu to an array of strings so that i can use the string array later. How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you store the option they've selected to a `String` array? Can they select more than one option at a time?

Comment: When you choose an item from an drow down menu, the result is just a `String/Object`, not an array: `String[]/Object[]`. How do you want to store the choise in a `String[]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList and store your selection by using a method getSelectedItem().

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible try to use Collection framework in java, it gives more flexibility.

**Example:**

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
JComboBox jb = new JComboBox();
jb.add("Vivek");
jb.add("Vishal");



jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        arr.add(jb.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
});
```